# seam3-security page restriction without using seam-faces

Tags: security, authorization, seam3

Is there other way to use seam3-security restricting page access via permission without using seam-faces?

In seam-faces we use something like:

```
@ViewConfig
public interface PagesConfig {
    static enum Pages1 {

        @ViewPattern("/*")
        @LoginView("/login.xhtml")
        @AccessDeniedView("/errors/403.xhtml")
        ALL,
    }
}
```

If we don't want seam-faces is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. To use the best out of seam-security you need to use seam-faces.